# Can't get ODBC to work with PostgreSQL on MacOS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: xcode, odbc, osx-lion

I got PostgreSQL 9.1 (from the official distro, not the built-in version) to install and talk nicely to a browser in MacOS Lion. However I can't get it to work with ODBC. I installed XCode in order to have the required libltdl.3.dylib, and also the psqlODBC driver. I then made a symlink in /usr/lib/libltdl.3.dylib so that psqlODBC would find the library. psqlODBC is registered in iodbcinst.ini. However, when I try to open a connection, I get two different errors. In iodbctest:

```
1: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen({/Library/PostgreSQL/psqlODBC/lib/psqlodbcw.so}, 6): image not found (0) SQLSTATE=00000
2: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded (0) SQLSTATE=IM003
```

And through an application:

```
[iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/psqlODBC/lib/psqlodbcw.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/psqlODBC/lib/psqlodbcw.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libltdl.
```

Both errors are puzzling. psqlodbcw.so is exactly where it's supposed to be, and so is libltdl.3.dylib. It seems the driver is truncating the library's filename at the first period, very odd.
Any thoughts?